# How does (Ultra) Lucky Cat work?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

These Felyne Cooking skills say that they give a chance to "receive more rewards at the end of the quest". But I know that some rewards are specific for certain monster parts (e.g. Mantles typically come from tail cutting or face breaking). Will the Lucky Cat skills increase the number of "part rewards" or does it simply increase the number of rewards for the quest only?

Comment: I suspect it's like the Fate armor skill.  Probably a direct analog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the quest rewards in the Monster Hunter series works is that you're guaranteed a certain number of rewards per quest, and then have a chance for additional rewards. More specifically, after the fixed rewards are rewarded the game then rolls (generates a random number) to see if an additional reward is given. If the roll is successful then an additional reward is granted, and another roll is made. This process continues until one of the rolls fails. This process takes place twice, and each time it uses a different table. You can see an example of a quest rewards table [here](http://kiranico.com/quest/v5/fell-the-lagiacrus).

The kitchen skills Lucky Cat, Ultra Lucky Cat and Unlucky Cat, along with Great Luck, Good Luck, Bad Luck, and Horrible Luck adjust the chance for the roll to be successful. Bad Luck, Horrible Luck and Unlucky Cat decrease the chance of a roll being successful, and the other Luck skills increase the chance of the skill being successful.

As for specific numbers, I can't provide those, since no one has actually managed to gain access to the source code of Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate. However, it's likely they are similiar to the numbers from previous games (which are known), and so I've provided the values for Tri below:

- **Great Luck / Ultra Lucky Cat**: 90% Chance
- **Good Luck / Lucky Cat**: 81% Chance
- **Default**: 69% Chance
- **Bad Luck / Unlucky Cat**: 50% Chance
- **Horrible Luck**: 25% Chance

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/943655-monster-hunter-tri/faqs/60448)

Comment: The source doesn't specifically state that the Kitchen Skills use the same percentages as the Fate skills, but I find it highly likely that they do.